# call delphi dll from visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, delphi, dll

I have DLL file which compiles in Delphi, functions export as __stdcall, and functions description txt file. I havn't got any source code.

And I'll use this DLL in visual studio c++ project. Google says that need use `LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress` , but GetProcAddress returns NULL if  exported function declared as __stdcall, i.e. I can't call function with its name. And others recomended using .def file, 
but I don't know what .def file, and what need for generating .def file, if I can use this way on my situation, please describe thoroughly.

**QA: How I can call these exported functions?**

Here I post my main.cpp file,  dll name and function name changed specially.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>


int main()
{
    //foo(80, 127);
    HMODULE hLib;
    hLib = LoadLibrary( _T("MyDLL.dll") );

    assert(hLib != NULL ); // pass !!


    int ( __stdcall *pFoo)(int, int);
    (FARPROC &)pFoo = GetProcAddress(hLib, _T("foo") );

    if (pFoo== NULL )
    {
        DWORD errc = GetLastError();
        printf("%u\n",errc); // it gets error 127

    }else{
        printf("success load\n");
    }
//  pFoo(04,1);

    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all I suggest that you stop using `tchar.h`, `_T`, etc. That was useful when you needed to compile for Windows 98. But it's 2014 and surely you can forget that Windows 98 ever existed. So compile your applications for `UNICODE` and use `L"..."` for wide literals.

Of course, `GetProcAddress` only receives 8 bit text. So your current code is incorrect. You must not use `_T("...")` for the function name parameter of `GetProcAddress`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) makes this clear.

Since your code compiles it must be that you are compiling for ANSI or MBCS. And if `GetProcAddress` returns `NULL` then clearly the DLL does not export a function with the name that you supply. Some possible reasons:

1. You did not export the function.
2. You exported the function but not by that name. Note that whilst Delphi is case insensitive, DLL functions importing/exporting is case sensitive. Perhaps you exported `Foo` rather than `foo`.

A trivial DLL that will work with the code in your question:

```
library MyDLL;

function foo(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := a + b;
end;

exports
  foo;

end.
```

Note that .def files simple are not pertinent here. Delphi does not use .def files. And the calling convention cannot be relevant either. The name used by Delphi to export a function is not influenced by the calling convention.